# Docker run command and docker-compose ENV variable passing results in different results. Why?

Tags: java, docker

Please consider a java app that is using spring profiles. There is a default local profile and a dev profile.

```
docker run -p 8080 repo/app -e SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
```

running this command will result in local profile.

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  my-app:
    image: repo/app:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev"
```

This will work correctly after running `docker-compose up`. I'm using the same docker image. In the Dockerfile I don't do anything other than running the jar. Not passing anything. Do you think it's some CLI related problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic syntax of `docker run` is

```bash
docker run \
  [docker options]
  image-name
  [command]
```

In your example, you have the `-e` option *after* the image name, so it's interpreted as the command to run.  If your Dockerfile specifies the main container command as an `ENTRYPOINT`, then your program will see this as arguments.

You need to move the `-e` option *before* the image name

```bash
docker run \
  -p 8080 \
  -e SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev \
  repo/app
```

In this specific case, since Spring Boot supports many ways of passing arguments, if the first container starts at all, then you could start it with

```bash
docker run -p 8080 repo/app --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

using a command-line argument instead of an environment variable.